# What space is $\mathbb{C}^2 \setminus Z$ equivalent to, where $Z = \{(x, y) \in \mathbb{C}^2 | x = 0 \ \text{or} \ y = 0\}$?

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

Let $Z = \{(x, y) \in \mathbb{C}^2 | x = 0 \ \text{or} \ y = 0\}$ and let $X = \mathbb{C}^2 \setminus Z$. What space is $X$ homotopy equivalent to?

I thought that this would be homotopy equivalent to the torus $T$ by the following reasoning. First,
$$
X = \{(x, y) | x \in \mathbb{C}, x \neq 0, y \in \mathbb{C}, y \neq 0\} = (\mathbb{C} \setminus \{0\}) \times (\mathbb{C}\setminus \{0\}).
$$
Now, since $\mathbb{C} \cong \mathbb{R}^2$, each of these factors is homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^2\setminus \{0\}$, which is homotopy equivalent to the circle $S^1$. Hence $X \simeq S^1 \times S^1 = T$.

This arose in a question asking what the homology of $X$ was, and the homologies in the answer key were not that of the torus, so I am wondering if I've gone wrong somewhere here.

Comment: I might be missing a subtlety, but your solution seems just fine with me. Could the "or" in the definition be exclusive?

Comment: @CaptainLama I've just double-checked; the wording of the problem (at least the part defining $Z$) is identical to what I've written here. So I can only hope it's not an exclusive or.

Comment: What's the homology in the answer key?

Comment: @QiaochuYuan the answer key gave $\mathbb{Z}$ for the zeroth homology and $\mathbb{Z}^2$ for the first and second (and trivial afterwards). It also uses something called Alexander duality, which I'm not familiar with.

Comment: That's strange. Your solution seems fine to me too. What's the name of the text? Can you reproduce the exact text of the exercise and the answer key?

Comment: Turns out it was a small typo errata in the solutions - it's since been fixed to agree with the above, so I guess the above reasoning is not in contradiction with their method. Thanks for your attention!